# Rename exe for different deployments

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I have a .Net c++/cli application (framework 3.5) which I want to deploy for different clients, the exe name should be different. When I change target name the files serialization error.

Comment: I don't understand why changing the target name causes a serialization error.  What is that error, anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a post-build event for this. Create a different post-build event for each configuration, and execute a rename command in the event.

Comment: Axarydax: Thanks a lot for this quick responds. Could you please explain how to do this in C++/CLI?

Comment: you do this in Project Properties, section Build Events->Post-Build Event, then use something like "ren $(TargetDir)\$(TargetFileName) $(TargetDir)\NEWNAME.exe"

Comment: Axarydax: Appreciate this help. I added the following to the project property Post-Build Event Command Line ren $(OutDir)$(TargetFileName) Nename.exe